# Skiasharp Undo/Redo buttons

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, skiasharp

I have a **SkiaSharp canvas** with bitmaps that you can `move/rotate/scale`, but now I want to create an `Undo/Redo` function on the canvas, but I have no idea how to start. I need to store every change or something.....

Can someone help me on the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just supporting the transformation of the surface (rotate, scale, translate) then all you need is to store the `TotalMatrix`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skcanvas.totalmatrix

On every change, take that and store is somewhere in a list of some sort. Then, to undo/redo, just use `SetMatrix`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skcanvas.setmatrix

That may be what you are looking for.

The `Save` and `Restore` may look tempting, but they are more for current transformations - save the state, transform and then restore. This allows for less complex maths when drawing a single image.

Answer (score 0):

Could https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skcanvas.restoretocount?view=skiasharp-1.68.1#SkiaSharp_SKCanvas_RestoreToCount_System_Int32_ be something of use to you?

This could mean that on every action you need to run a `save()` which I'm unaware how much space would require in terms of memory.

This `save` and restore from count was the closest thing I could find for undo.

If you want to add a redo, then it's a much more complicated thing, as you need to solve the what happens if I undo something, make another change and freddo
Redo the undone action.